# Chrome Inspector after latest update needs scrolling - Any fix?

Tags: google-chrome

I am using chrom's dev tools a lot and especially the inspector to see the elements on a page. After I updated chrome a week ago the inspect element is now 9 out of 10 times hidden and I need to scroll to get to the inspect part. As I am using this soo much it iritates me a lot . Is there any way I can change this ...so I want the inspect part always to be visable the moment I do a right click

This is how it is a lot of times now
[image: no inspect]

And this is how it is when scrolled and I want this to be the default display
[image: inspect]

it happend after the latest update of Chrome. I have version  120.0.6099.110

Comment: This is the new redesign of the entire UI code-named `CR2023`. You can complain about the problem in https://crbug.com.